# XMLGregorianCalendar with 6 milliseconds

Tags: java, spring-boot, date-format, xmlgregoriancalendar

I try to get a `XMLGregorianCalendar` entry  which looks like
`"06-09-2022 17:05:28:113319"`.

I call an extern api to get a timestamp in style like below. But I need it to call another api.

For the data structure I use many WSDLs. So I implemented an Dateadapter which will convert the timestamp into something like `2022-09-06T17:07:21.319+02:00`. But it did´t work.

I´m using Java - Springboot.

Dateadapter:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, XMLGregorianCalendar> {
    private static final String DATE_STRING = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSX";

    @Override
    public String marshal(XMLGregorianCalendar v) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_STRING);
        return dateFormat.format(v.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public XMLGregorianCalendar unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_STRING);

        gregorianCalendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse(v));
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
    }

}
```